# How to re-use vba code (sub) into several other subs

Tags: excel, vba

I've got 50 wb's Im currently updating using vba. But it's a drag writing (and updating) the same code 50 times, so I'm trying to come up with a method to re-use code. All wb's are equal in structure (sheetnames etc), and the basic "update-vba" should therefore be reusable in all "UpdateGroup-subs". My idea is to place definitions and basic "update-vba" in subs outside the "UpdateGroup-subs", and call upon them when running each "UpdateGroup-sub". But I'm getting a compile error (variable not defined). Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Anyone that can help me out on how to get this to work? I'm uploading 2 versions, one that is working (repeating all code in each "UpdateGroup-sub"), and one that's my attempt at simplify this...

WORKS:

```
Option Explicit
'************************************************************************

Sub UpdateAllGroups_1_WorksOK()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
StartTime = Timer

    Call UpdateGroup1
    Call UpdateGroup2

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "All Updates is done in " & MinutesElapsed, vbInformation, "Message"

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup1()

'DEFINITIONS
Dim fPath, ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo, ReportR2vo As String
Dim WbReport, WbGroup As Workbook
Dim sh_Dash, sh_NewR2ob, sh_NewR1vo, sh_NewR2vo, sh_Time As Worksheet

    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
        fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
        End If

Set WbGroup = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group1_(M).xlsm")    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
    With WbGroup
        Set sh_Dash = .Worksheets("Dash")
        Set sh_NewR2ob = .Worksheets("NewR2ob")
        Set sh_NewR1vo = .Worksheets("NewR1vo")
        Set sh_NewR2vo = .Worksheets("NewR2vo")
        Set sh_Time = .Worksheets("Time")
    End With

ThisGroupWb = "Group1_(M).xlsm"     'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR2ob = "R2ob - Group1.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR1vo = "R1vo - Group1.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR2vo = "R2vo - Group1.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub


'NEW REPORTS
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2ob\" & ReportR2ob)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2ob.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R1vo\" & ReportR1vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2vo\" & ReportR2vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR1vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False


'STORE AND CLOSE GROUP-WB
Application.Goto sh_Dash.Range("A1"), True
WbGroup.Save
WbGroup.Close False

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup2()

'DEFINITIONS
Dim fPath, ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo, ReportR2vo As String
Dim WbReport, WbGroup As Workbook
Dim sh_Dash, sh_NewR2ob, sh_NewR1vo, sh_NewR2vo, sh_Time As Worksheet

    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
        fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
        End If

Set WbGroup = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group2_(M).xlsm")    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
    With WbGroup
        Set sh_Dash = .Worksheets("Dash")
        Set sh_NewR2ob = .Worksheets("NewR2ob")
        Set sh_NewR1vo = .Worksheets("NewR1vo")
        Set sh_NewR2vo = .Worksheets("NewR2vo")
        Set sh_Time = .Worksheets("Time")
    End With

ThisGroupWb = "Group2_(M).xlsm"     'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR2ob = "R2ob - Group2.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR1vo = "R1vo - Group2.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
ReportR2vo = "R2vo - Group2.xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub


'NEW REPORTS
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2ob\" & ReportR2ob)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2ob.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R1vo\" & ReportR1vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2vo\" & ReportR2vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR1vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False


'STORE AND CLOSE GROUP-WB
Application.Goto sh_Dash.Range("A1"), True
WbGroup.Save
WbGroup.Close False

End Sub
'************************************************************************
```

NOT WORKING:

```
Option Explicit
'************************************************************************

Sub UpdateAllGroups_2_DoesntWork()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
StartTime = Timer

    Call UpdateGroup1
    Call UpdateGroup2

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "All Updates is done in " & MinutesElapsed, vbInformation, "Message"

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub Definitions()

Dim fPath, ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo, ReportR2vo As String
Dim WbReport, WbGroup As Workbook
Dim sh_Dash, sh_NewR2ob, sh_NewR1vo, sh_NewR2vo, sh_Time As Worksheet

    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
        fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
        End If

    With WbGroup
        Set sh_Dash = .Worksheets("Dash")
        Set sh_NewR2ob = .Worksheets("NewR2ob")
        Set sh_NewR1vo = .Worksheets("NewR1vo")
        Set sh_NewR2vo = .Worksheets("NewR2vo")
        Set sh_Time = .Worksheets("Time")
    End With

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroups()

Set WbGroup = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ThisGroupWb")

'NEW REPORTS
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2ob\" & ReportR2ob)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2ob.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R1vo\" & ReportR1vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False

    Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2vo\" & ReportR2vo)
    WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR1vo.Range("A1")
    WbReport.Close False


'STORE AND CLOSE GROUP-WB
Application.Goto sh_Dash.Range("A1"), True
WbGroup.Save
WbGroup.Close False

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup1()

Call Definitions
    ThisGroupWb = "Group1_(M).xlsm"
    ReportR2ob = "R2ob - Group1.xls"
    ReportR1vo = "R1vo - Group1.xls"
    ReportR2vo = "R2vo - Group1.xls"
Call UpdateGroups

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup2()

Call Definitions
    ThisGroupWb = "Group2_(M).xlsm"
    ReportR2ob = "R2ob - Group2.xls"
    ReportR1vo = "R1vo - Group2.xls"
    ReportR2vo = "R2vo - Group2.xls"
Call UpdateGroups

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line exactly do you get the error ?

Comment: Just as a remark: Declarations like that `Dim fPath, ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo, ReportR2vo As String` only declare the last variable as string, all others are variant, for an explanation look [here](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2012/10/declaring-multiple-variables-with-one-dim-statement/).

Comment: `ThisGroupWb = "Group1_(M).xlsm"`      in "UpdateGroup1-sub". And if I put this line on "pause", error appear on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use arguments in your subroutine as follows:

```
'Version 1: using single argument GroupNumber

Option Explicit
'************************************************************************

Sub UpdateAllGroups()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
StartTime = Timer

    Call UpdateGroup(1)
    Call UpdateGroup(2)

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "All Updates is done in " & MinutesElapsed, vbInformation, "Message"

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup(ByVal GroupNumber As Long)

    'DEFINITIONS
    Dim fPath, ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo, ReportR2vo As String
    Dim WbReport, WbGroup As Workbook
    Dim sh_Dash, sh_NewR2ob, sh_NewR1vo, sh_NewR2vo, sh_Time As Worksheet

        fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
            If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
            fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
            End If

    'Note that path is composed using supplied argument:
    Set WbGroup = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group" & GroupNumber & "_(M).xlsm")
        With WbGroup
            Set sh_Dash = .Worksheets("Dash")
            Set sh_NewR2ob = .Worksheets("NewR2ob")
            Set sh_NewR1vo = .Worksheets("NewR1vo")
            Set sh_NewR2vo = .Worksheets("NewR2vo")
            Set sh_Time = .Worksheets("Time")
        End With

    'Same here:
    ThisGroupWb = "Group" & GroupNumber & "_(M).xlsm"     'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
    ReportR2ob = "R2ob - Group" & GroupNumber & ".xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
    ReportR1vo = "R1vo - Group" & GroupNumber & ".xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
    ReportR2vo = "R2vo - Group" & GroupNumber & ".xls"    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub


    'NEW REPORTS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2ob\" & ReportR2ob)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2ob.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R1vo\" & ReportR1vo)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2vo.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2vo\" & ReportR2vo)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR1vo.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False


    'STORE AND CLOSE GROUP-WB
    Application.Goto sh_Dash.Range("A1"), True
    WbGroup.Save
    WbGroup.Close False

End Sub
```

Or, closer to what you've done:

```
'Version 2: using ThisGroupWb, ReportR2ob, ReportR1vo and ReportR2vo

Option Explicit
'************************************************************************

Sub UpdateAllGroups()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
StartTime = Timer

    Call UpdateGroup("Group1_(M).xlsm", "R2ob - Group1.xls", "R1vo - Group1.xls", "R2vo - Group1.xls")
    Call UpdateGroup("Group2_(M).xlsm", "R2ob - Group2.xls", "R1vo - Group2.xls", "R2vo - Group2.xls")

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "All Updates is done in " & MinutesElapsed, vbInformation, "Message"

End Sub
'************************************************************************

Private Sub UpdateGroup(ByVal ThisGroupWb As String, ByVal ReportR2ob As String, ByVal ReportR1vo As String, ByVal ReportR2vo As String)

    'DEFINITIONS
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim WbReport, WbGroup As Workbook
    Dim sh_Dash, sh_NewR2ob, sh_NewR1vo, sh_NewR2vo, sh_Time As Worksheet

        fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
            If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
            fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
            End If

    Set WbGroup = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisGroupWb)    'must be changed in each UpdateGroup-sub
        With WbGroup
            Set sh_Dash = .Worksheets("Dash")
            Set sh_NewR2ob = .Worksheets("NewR2ob")
            Set sh_NewR1vo = .Worksheets("NewR1vo")
            Set sh_NewR2vo = .Worksheets("NewR2vo")
            Set sh_Time = .Worksheets("Time")
        End With

    'Already assigned (call arguments)
    'ThisGroupWb = ...
    'ReportR2ob = ...
    'ReportR1vo = ...
    'ReportR2vo = ...


    'NEW REPORTS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2ob\" & ReportR2ob)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2ob.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R1vo\" & ReportR1vo)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR2vo.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False

        Set WbReport = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2vo\" & ReportR2vo)
        WbReport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy sh_NewR1vo.Range("A1")
        WbReport.Close False


    'STORE AND CLOSE GROUP-WB
    Application.Goto sh_Dash.Range("A1"), True
    WbGroup.Save
    WbGroup.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't change my underlying problem. My wish is in some way to be able to store definitions and "UpdateGroups-vba" in such a way that I can Call upon it and re-use it in each "UpdateGroup-sub".

Comment: Take a deeper look: there is only one subroutine: `UpdateGroup`. When you call it, you must supply an argument, `GroupNumber`. Then, when subroutine is called, relevant parts are modified to supplied group.

Comment: I'll be d.... Your code works just fine! But my head is having some trouble on grasping just why it does so... :-) Are there limitations to your method? Will it still work if group-wb's is named "s3g1", "s3g2", and so on? Or does the code just run through all wb's it finds in this folder?

Comment: By the way: Thanks a lot @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ for posting the solution to cure my headache! :-))

Comment: This code won't "auto-run" - you must run macro or some other mechanism calls `UpdateAllGroups`. Then, as in your question, `UpdateAllGroups` will call `UpdateGroup(1)` and `UpdateGroup(2)`, simply that, no more automation. About other group names, you must identify all needed inputs to your subroutine, and then make them as arguments and adapt code to those.